# Setting body color using Bourobon + Neat

Tags: mustache, bourbon, neat

I can't quite get body backround color to show up.

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
@import "neat/neat";
body {background: red;}
```

Im also using the Mustache framework so my html is:

```
<body id="{{namespace}}" style="margin:0;">

<div id="wrapper">  

<%> commons/header %>

    <%#home? %>
        <%> pages/home %>
    <%/home? %>

    <%#sobre? %>
        <%> pages/sobre %>
    <%/sobre? %>

    <%#galeria? %>
        <%> pages/galeria %>
    <%/galeria? %>

    <%#contato? %>
    <%> pages/contato %>
    <%/contato? %>

    <%> commons/footer %>

</div>

</body>
```

I tried many variations already. It seems so simple, but it's driving me crazy.
Any ideas?

Comment: You sure you included the compiled css into your html?

Comment: Hey @michaellee yeah, it's being compiled on the output css. Maybe it's something wrong with my template framework that's overruning stuff... have no idea.

Comment: anyway you can throw up your code somewhere that I can have a look?

Comment: Sure bro: https://github.com/abarro/template the htmls are in marckup and scss in stylesheets. They get compiled to assets/css

Comment: I'm not too familiar with mustache but I don't see any reference to your css in your head block anywhere.

Comment: hey @michaellee thanks for taking a look. It's kind of automagic. I have a ruby gem that pipes the scss directly into assets/css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Answer is that this turned out to be a very specific problem related to my custom designed template system.

So I set the body color elsewhere to make things workout.

I believe this wont help anyone out there, but I only realised it was so specific after this question.

Thanks